# How to determine if a View has been rotated

Tags: android, android-view

As the title suggests, I would like to know programmatically if a given View has been rotated already. Here is my animation function:

```
public static void AnimateArrowDown(View v)
    {
        RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 90.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        anim.setDuration(200);
        anim.setFillAfter(true);
        v.findViewById(R.id.arrow_imageview).startAnimation(anim);
    }
```

I'm animating an arrow right to down inside a ListView. My problem is when the view is redraw for some list elements the arrow previously rotated for another list item gets passed to this new list item. Hence, I would like to determine if the arrow in the ListView has been rotated and if so then rotate the arrow to its actual position.

Comment: I'd add a static variable (flag) so you can check the value of the variable before you actually rotate it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`View.getRotation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getRotation()) method.

```
float rotation = v.findViewById(R.id.arrow_imageview).getRotation();
```

Then you can determine the value is default (`0.0f`; not rotated) or not (`90.0f`; rotated).

(Note: However, I would also prefer another approach using state flags like Saehun Sean Oh mentions in his comment. I don't think they need to be static but to be field members, and keep boolean states there.)